# Active Record legacy table with no primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, primary-key, legacy-database

I'm connecting my Rails application with a legacy database. Some of this tables don't have a primary key and I have no way to add one.

Is there any way to to configure an Active Model not to have a primary key?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define primary key by using `self.primary_key = <pk_field>` like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = "user"
    self.primary_key = "id"
end
```

Comment: While that's useful information it does not answer the question. I've tried assigning `nil` or `false` as primary key and that does not work.

Comment: Is there any field in your database that is unique to each record?

Comment: Unfortunately no. The table is poorly structured. I could use a combination of fields as a composite key, but that won't be unique either.